# Understanding the syntax *y[ ] passed as parameter

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-definition

I am trying to understand `C` code and I have stumbled across the following function definitions:

```
int foo(int n, double *y[]);
```

I am having trouble understanding how to handle and interpret `*y[]`. This syntax is being used in several functions but handled differently. In this example, `foo1()` it is used as a bidimensional array:

```
int foo1(int n, double *y[]){
 double var0 = 0;
 double var1 = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var1 += y[i][1] ;
    var0 += y[i][0] ;
 }
 // do stuff
 return 0;
}
```

And here the same syntax is used, but `*y[]` is used as an array, but here they use the pointer `*` notation:

```
int foo2(int n, double *y[]){
 double var0 = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var0 += *y[i] ;
 }
 // do stuff
 return 0;
}
```

Could you be so kind to provide a precise explanation of what `*y[]` means and why it can be used so flexibly as a function parameter?

Comment: [https://cdecl.org/?q=double+*y%5B%5D](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+*y%5B%5D)

Comment: It may help to read the parameter as `double* y[]` (and some coding standards enforce this spacing) because this makes it clearer that `y` is an array of pointers to double. Each pointer can be thought of as, say, the first member of a row in a matrix, or as an individual `double` at an arbitrary location. That may be why you see different ways of accessing the data through the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter declaration

```
double *y[]
```

declares an array of unknown size with elements of the type `double *`.  That is it is an array of pointers of the type `double *`.

It seems the first parameter of this function

```
int foo(int n, double *y[]);
```

that is the variable `n` specifies the number of elements in the array.

This expression

```
y[i]
```

gives the `i-th` element of the array. as the element of the array is a pointer (for example a pointer to the first element of an array with two elements) then these expressions

```
y[i][1] 
y[i][0]
```

yield the pointed elements.

As for this expression

```
*y[i]
```

then it is equivalent to the expression

```
y[i][0]
```

To make it more clear I will provide a demonstrated program where instead of an array of the type `double * []` there is used an array of the type `char * []`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( size_t n, char *  s[] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; s[i][j] != '\0'; j++ )
        {
            putchar( s[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * s[] =
    {
        "Hello",
        "World"
    };
    
    f( sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ), s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible in this case to obtain the number of elements each `y[i]` has? Using `sizeof(y[i])/sizeof(y[i][0])`

Comment: @D1X It is impossible because pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single element or to the first element of an array. In the demonstrative program in my answer I am using strings that  terminated by the zero character '\0'. So for strings you can determine their lengths. But for other arrays that do not have a sentinel value you need explicitly to pass the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

In a function declaration, parameters with array type are converted to pointers.  So the parameter `double *y[]` is exactly equivalent to `double **y`.

Regarding the use of `*y[i]` vs `y[i][0]`, that comes from the equivalency of the array index operator `[]` to pointer arithmetic and dereference.

The expression `E1[E2]` is exactly equivalent to `*((E1)+(E2))`  This means that  `y[i][0]` is the same as `*(y[i]+0)` or `*y[i]`.

Comment: In the terminology of the C standard, an array declaration is *adjusted* to be a pointer declaration, not *converted*. Values are converted, and, in a declaration, there is no value to be converted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the usage in `foo1`, `y` is an array of pointers to 2-element arrays of `double`<sup>1</sup>, something like this:

```
   +---+                                                  +---+
y: |   | y[0] ------------------------------------------> |   | y[0][0]
   +---+                                 +---+            +---+
   |   | y[1] -------------------------> |   | y[1][0]    |   | y[0][1]
   +---+                                 +---+            +---+
    ...                                  |   | y[1][1]
   +---+              +---+              +---+
   |   | y[n-1] ----> |   | y[n-1][0]
   +---+              +---+
                      |   | y[n-1][1]
                      +---+
```

and is likely declared as

```
double *x[N];  // or some other name, just picking x for convenience
```

and either initialized with addresses of existing arrays:

```
double a[2], b[2], c[2], ...;
double *x[N] = { a, b, c, ... };
```

or memory is allocated dynamically:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  x[i] = malloc( sizeof *x[i] * 2 );
```

in the calling function.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array of character type in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call `foo1` or `foo2` with the `x` as the argument, as in

```
foo1( N, x );
foo2( N, x );
```

the *expression* `x` is converted from type "N-element array of pointer to `double`" to type "pointer to pointer to `double`", and the address of the first element (`&x[0]`) is what actually gets passed to the function.

In a function parameter declaration, any parameters of the form `T a[N]` or `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a` - IOW `a` is always treated as a pointer to `T`, not as an array.

So even though `y` is declared as `double *y[]` in the function parameter list, it's actually being treated as `double **y`.

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address, offset `i` elements (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.  So `y[i]` is equivalent to `*(y + i)` and `y[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(y + i) + j)`.  This also means that the expression `*y` is equivalent to `y[0]` and `*y[i]` is equivalent to `y[i][0]`.

```
*y    == *(y + 0)    == y[0]
*y[i] == *(y[i] + 0) == y[i][0]
```

---

1. More correctly, each `y[i]` points to the first element of a 2-element array of `double`.